# VSCode Remote SSH cannot identify private key file

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

Been trying to solve this for hours already. Already searched the net and follow tutorials but nothing is working.

In my Windows local machine I installed Remote SSH plugin in VSCode. I'm trying to connect to my remote linux server.

My config file looks like this (changed hostname and user to dummy values for security).

```
Host RemoteServer
    HostName remote.server.infra
    User user123
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privkey
```

When trying to connect to New Host. It keeps prompting for password.
As per checking the logs it is saying

```
no such identity: C:\\Users\\user123/.ssh/privkey: No such file or directory
```

This privkey file is the exact file I'm using in my putty when connecting to remote server.
What am I missing?

EDIT:
Finally figured it out. I had to convert my private key to openssh format with puttygen.

Answer (score 13):

In addition of [using an openSSH format](https://superuser.com/a/232365/141), I would also put the full path in the config file:

```
Host RemoteServer
    HostName remote.server.infra
    User user123
    IdentityFile /c:/Users/user123/.ssh/privkey
```

Note that the SSH URL then becomes:

```
ssh -Tv RemoteServer
```

Note: [Başar Söker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5401674/ba%C5%9Far-s%C3%B6ker) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160457/vscode-remote-ssh-cannot-identify-private-key-file/66167756?noredirect=1#comment123396564_66167756):

> I also needed to add a colon to my path.
> Here how it looks like:
>
> ```
>  IdentityFile /c:/Users/username/.ssh/privatekey.pem
> ```

---

Note: [reukiodo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291016/reukiodo) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160457/vscode-remote-ssh-cannot-identify-private-key-file/66167756?noredirect=1#comment132065135_66167756):

> If you copy/paste the private key, it MUST end with a newline, or it will also result in this same error.

Reminder: only the public key can be copied elsewhere. The private key should remain on your computer.

Comment: I also needed to add a colon to my path. Here how it looks like: /c:/Users/username/.ssh/privatekey.pem

Comment: @BaşarSöker Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visiblity.

Comment: If you copy/paste the private key, it MUST end with a newline, or it will also result in this same error.

Comment: @reukiodo Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

if you have generated public private key pair using putty you need to convert the private key using putty generation conversion or else it will not work and it will show public key access denied

Comment: as I struggle to execute this very valid point, you need to click on "conversions"->"export openSSH key", that will give you the (private key) file you need.